# 404 Not found after configuration of SSL certificate with Cert Bot and Nginx in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, nginx, ssl

The API was working perfectly until I added a SSL certificate with cert bot, and now I am always getting **404 error** when accessing it. The SSL certificate is valid. I have the same API running before adding an SSL certificate, which is working fine. The cluster is hosted on digital ocean. Pods are running fine and no logs are shown. **When accessing the service over the IP it works perfectly fine**

Let me know which else of information you need!

Ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: btcapi-ingress
  namespace: btcapi
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - example.me
      secretName: letsencrypt-secret-prodv2
  rules:
    - host: example.me
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: btcapi-service
                port:
                  number: 80
```

```
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /   btcapi-service:443 (10.244.0.108:80,10.244.0.117:80,10.244.0.38:80)
              /   btcapi-service:80 (10.244.0.108:80,10.244.0.117:80,10.244.0.38:80)
Annotations:  cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-prod
              kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
              nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

Issuer

```
apiVersion: cert-manager.io/v1
kind: Issuer
metadata:
  name: letsencrypt-prod
  namespace: btcapi
spec:
  acme:
    email: email@outlook.com  # Set your email
    server: https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
    privateKeySecretRef:
      name: letsencrypt-secret-prod  # Choose another name
    solvers:
    - http01:
        ingress:
          class: nginx  # Specify your Ingress controller
```

Deployment

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: btc-api-server
  labels:
    app: btc-api-server
  namespace: btcapi
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: btc-api-server
  template:
    metadata:
      name: btc-api-server
      labels:
        app: btc-api-server
    spec:
      containers:
          - name: btc-api-server
            image: myname/btcapi:0.0.6
            imagePullPolicy: Always
            ports:
              - name: api-access-port
                containerPort: 80
            #resources:
            #  requests:
            #    memory: "2048Mi"
            #  limits:
            #    memory: "2Gi"

      restartPolicy: Always
```

Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: btcapi-service
  labels:
    app: btcapi-service
  namespace: btcapi
spec:
  selector:
    app: btc-api-server
  ports:
    - name: http
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
    - name: redis
      protocol: TCP
      port: 6379
      targetPort: 6379
```

```
IP:                10.245.204.32
IPs:               10.245.204.32
Port:              http  80/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.108:80,10.244.0.117:80,10.244.0.38:80
Port:              https  443/TCP
TargetPort:        80/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.108:80,10.244.0.117:80,10.244.0.38:80
Port:              redis  6379/TCP
TargetPort:        6379/TCP
Endpoints:         10.244.0.108:6379,10.244.0.117:6379,10.244.0.38:6379
```